# How to define the area from the Riemanian metric?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

Consider the Poincaré upper half plane $\mathbb{H} = \{z \in \mathbb{C} \ : \ \Im(z) > 0\}$. This can be endowed with the Riemanian hyperbolic metric, defined by
$$g_z(u,v) = \frac{1}{\Im(z)^2}\langle u, v \rangle$$
where $\langle \cdot, \cdot\rangle$ is the usual euclidian inner product, $z$ is a point of $\mathbb{H}$ and $u, v$ are tangent vectors at $z$, i.e. elements of $T_z \mathbb{H}$.

This Riemanian metric allows for instance to define a notion of length, integrating along a path the "local" norm of the speed. However, what about areas? I see that the formula for the hyperbolic area of a domain $B$ is often given to be
$$\operatorname{Area}(B) = \int_B \frac{\mathrm dx \mathrm dy}{y^2}$$
but can this be deduced from the Riemannian data, i.e. the definition of $g_z$?

Comment: The notion you are looking for is that of the Riemannian [volume form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_form). In the specific case of the hyperbolic half plane, it is $\frac{dx\wedge dy}{y^2}$ and yields to the formula you gave. For the $n$-dimensional hyperbolic half-space $\{(x_1,\ldots,x_n) \mid x_n>0\}$ with metric $\frac{1}{{x_n}^2} \langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$, it will be $\frac{dx_1\wedge\cdots \wedge dx_n}{{x_n}^n}$, and the volume of a subset $B$ is $\int_B \frac{1}{{x_n}^n}dx_1\cdots dx_n$.

Comment: At that [volume form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_form#Riemannian_volume_form) link, see also the sublink [Riemannian volume form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_form#Riemannian_volume_form) for a general formula in coordinates.